# Adding Next & Previous Buttons To jquery Roundabout

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am using jQuery Roundabout (http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) to rotate through 3 images. I am not aware of how I can add "Next" and "Prev" buttons to help the user rotate through the images. Currently I have it set to auto rotate or slide to next image if the user clicks on the image itself. However, I would like to also add the ability of these buttons as a secondary means of navigation. Is there something in the existing code that needs to be changed in order to make this work or does it require separate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get a button, give it a class of `next` then in your roundabout, set to option to the next button.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul').roundabout({
         btnNext: ".next"
      });
   });
</script>
```

same for `btnPrev`

http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/#/api